# Angular Reactive Form - Validate form on button click

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formbuilder, formgroups

I have a form in which I am using `FormBuilder` to create my form. **I need to validate it when the button is clicked.**

Below is my HTML:

```
<input id="user-name" name="userName" placeholder="Enter Username" formControlName="username" class="form-control" />
<label class="form-label" for="user-name">Username</label>

<div class="text-danger" *ngIf="loginForm.controls['username'].touched && loginForm.controls['username'].errors?.['required']">Please enter the username</div>
```

Below is .ts file code:

```js
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.generateForm();
}

generateForm() {
  this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    username: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
    password: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  });
}
```

Now, I don't want my validations to work before hitting the button. I want to make it work when I will hit the button, it will show me errors if any.

Any suggestions/solutions will help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create `submitted` flag.

```js
submitted = true;
```

2. Add `(ngSubmit)` event and update `submitted` to `true`. This indicates that when the form is submitted, the `submitted` flag is updated to `true`.

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="submitted = true">
  
  ...

  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

3. Show the error when `submitted` is true.

```
<div
  class="text-danger"
  *ngIf="submitted && loginForm.controls['username'].errors?.['required']"
>
  Please enter the username
</div>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6wqcag?file=src/app/app.component.html)

---

**Additional**

You may find out that when you submit the form when the field is not filled, it shows the error message *(Correct behavior)*. You fill in the field, the error message is gone *(Correct behavior)*. When you try to clear the field (to blank), an error message has appeared *(Wrong behavior)*.

This is due to the `submitted` will be *forever* true when the form is submitted. For such scenario, you need to subscribe the form's `valueChanges` event and reset the `submitted` flag when the user inputs and the form is submitted previously.

```js
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs';

this.loginForm.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(500)).subscribe((_) => {
  if (this.submitted) this.submitted = false;
});
```

[(Improved) Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mczwrj?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: many thanks to you. It's working as I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can create a function to mark all controls on the form as touched and fire it if the form is invalid.

```
submitForm(): void {
    if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
        this.markFormGroupTouched(this.loginForm);
        return;
    }
    // submit form actions
}

markFormGroupTouched(formGroup: FormGroup): void {
    ( Object as any).values(formGroup.controls).forEach(control => {
        control.markAsTouched();
        if (control.controls) {
            this.markFormGroupTouched(control);
        }
    });
}
```

I hope this help you, regards.